# How can I create a dropdown menu for Tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 7 tables in one sheet. One is "Current Week" for stock price closed at the end of the week and "Net Position" for what the position is (Long minus Short).. I have 7 different stocks and I want to make a dropdown menu so I can compare 2 tables side by side and switch thru all 7 of them. Is this possible?

[image]

I want only 2 tables at one time side by side. I also want a dropdown menu on the EUR and GBP row where I can change the name of the stock and get the data to pop up below (Data for the Current Week and Net Position CW & NP).

I tried to create a normal dropdown menu but it will not allow me to dropdown 2 columns of data.

Comment: you will need VBA for that

Comment: This can be done but I am concerned about your comment “but it will not allow me to drop down two columns.”  You’re not dropping down two columns.  The dropdown menu contains a list of values, and that’s it.  There’s no logic in the dropdown cell that “pushes” the data into the columns.  Rather, in the columns are formulas that look to see what value is selected in the drop down cell, and based on that, retrieve the data to fill the columns.  Your wording suggested to me that you may be misunderstanding the logic behind how this should work.